# center of mass 3d matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry, computer-vision, physics

I have a sparse 3d volume (cube), at each x,y location I want to create a sphere with radius r, with center located at x,y,z.  For  each sphere I want to compute the center of mass.

My questions:

1. The points within each sphere are not evenly distributed, so the center of my mass is not the centroid, how to I compute the center of mass ? I found many different ways...
2. I need to compute this at each `size(x)*size(y)` times, which can be quite large, 
   I can create a 3d sphere like this:

   ```
   w = ceil(r)*2+1;
   [x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:w,1:w,1:w);
   xc = floor(w./2)+1;
   yc = floor(w./2)+1;
   zc = floor(w./2)+1;   
   mask = (x-xc).^2 + (y-yc).^2 + (z-zc).^2 <= r.^2;
   mask = double(mask);
   ```

but that will make me go with loop for each point, and will be time consuming.
Thanks
matlabit

Comment: do you have the point coordinates beforehand, or will you determine them randomly?

Comment: I have them, they are actually 1:size(x), 1:size(y),1:size(z)

Comment: then the center of mass will be (1+size(x))/2, (1+size(y))/2, (1+size(z))/2

Comment: I could not completely understand your question, do you want to calculate the centroid of all spheres, or the cube?

Comment: @fatih_k, each point in each sphere has a different mass, so the center of mass is not the centroid, the spheres are taken at locations withing the cubes, it doesn't really matter, I mentioned it because I wanted to emphasis is should be fast since the cube is big and I need to perform it x*y times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the update step of [K-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Standard_algorithm), that will find the center of mass for your sphere.

To find the points that should be included in that sphere calculate and threshold the [euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Three_dimensions) between the centroid of the sphere and each point. If the distance is less than your sphere's radius then include it.

Do this in a three deep nested for loop over your set of x,y,z sphere centroids, and you're done.

Comment: ok, does center of mass in this case will be (for each x,y,z): xc = sum (x_coord * point mass) / sum(all points mass) ?

Comment: Assuming that you limit the points to only those which are within your current sphere, that sounds right.

Comment: Any idea on how to avoid 3 loops in matlab ?

Comment: I suggested the 3 loops for simplicities sake, but if you really want to avoid them you could use a single loop over the vector `1:(max_X*max_Y*max_Z)` then use `ind2sub` to covert it back into a 3d coordinate.